# Errors when working with protocols as if they were classes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, protocols

I have a protocol like this:

```
protocol Moveable {
    var moveSpeed: Float { get set }
}
```

And in one of my classes that don't conform to "Moveable" I have a function like this:

```
var moveables: [Moveables]()
func checkMoveable(mov: Moveable) -> Bool {
        for m in moveables {
            if m === mov {  // <- Error
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

I get this error:

> Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'Moveable' operands

also tried with "==" instead of "==="

And in another function that relies on the previous one:

```
func removeMoveable(mov: Moveable) {
        if checkMoveable(mov) {
            self.moveables = moveables.filter({$0 !== mov})// <- Error
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Moveable' to expected argument type
>   'AnyObject?'

If "Moveable" was a class instead of being a protocol none of these errors would appear.

Comment: What is the type of `Moveables`? Is it `[Moveable!]`?

Comment: What classes implement the protocol?

Comment: You may have to make your protocols inherit from `Equatable` so they can use those operators. Like so: `protocol Moveable: Equatable { ... }`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes it's an array. And the classes that implement Moveable are SKSpriteNode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity operator `===` applies only to reference types (classes). Your protocol can be adopted by either reference or value types, so something whose only type information is that protocol can't be used with the identity operator.

If you want your protocol to be adopted only by classes, declare it thusly:

```
protocol Movable: class { //...
```

Or make it extend a protocol that's already restricted to classes:

```
protocol Movable: NSObjectProtocol { //...
```

The equivalence operator `==` applies only to types that are `Equatable`. If you want to use that operator on two `Movable`s, you'll need to declare that for a type to be `Movable` it must also  conform to `Equatable`:

```
protocol Movable: Equatable { //...
```

Since it seems you're looking for a particular `SKSpriteNode` instance, the first (making `===` work) is probably what you want.

Comment: The ": class" thing is completely new to me, Thanks.